# jQuery, checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have the following code :

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Club" onclick="getselectedcheckbox()"checked/>Club<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Pub" onclick="getselectedcheckbox()" checked/>Pub<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Home" onclick="getselectedcheckbox()"/>Home<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="Concert" onclick="getselectedcheckbox"/>Concert<br/>
```

```
<script>
function displayVals() {
var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
   }

$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
</script>
```

I am trying to get all the checkbox checked, to then send it with ajax.
But right now, I have 1  different alert for each checkboxes, is there a way to get all the checked values in one string ?

I've heard of .join(), but I don't really know where to put it in my code. Still beginning with Javascript / jquery :/

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Loneept

Comment: sounds like you are after http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Ya, serialize your FORM: `$('form').serialize()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get values of checked checkboxes into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170828/jquery-get-values-of-checked-checkboxes-into-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get all the checked values in one string ?

In your map, return the checkbox value, then use `get()` which retrieves the JavaScript array of values from the jQuery object. Finally, use `join()` to convert to a comma separated string.

```
var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

The result would be (with all checked):

```
Club,Pub,Home,Concert
```

Comment: This answering question as asked but as OP wants to send it using ajax, this seems better to serialize the FORM imho

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly.
I'll look into the serialize later, when i'll want to optimize the code :)

Answer (score 4):

Declare a array and push all the values into it, example:

```
   var selected = [];
   function displayVals() {
      var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
         selected.push(this.value);
      });
   }

 var stringArray =  selected.join();
```

use [array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert array to string

Comment: This isn't answering question which is how to get a string

Answer (score 1):

Give a form id like `myform` and simply use:

```
$('#myform').serialize();
```

> **Note:** It will not give unchecked checkboxes values

If you want to get unchecked values also then you need to explicitly set unchecked checkboxe's value false before serialize.

```
$('#myform').find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('value', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function displayVals() {
    var names = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

     return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to select every input called = "type". You'll have to modify the `input`tag in displayVals like this

```
function displayVals() {
var checkedValues = $('input[name=type]:checked').map(function() {
alert(this.value);
});
```