# To pass the array values present in the jquery function of a jsp page to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I need help in passing the values present in the jquery function of a jsp page to a servlet.

I have grouped the set of values present in the checked check box row using the jquery function.Now I need to insert those values into my database. I tried to pass the values using `request.getParameterValues()`,but it is not working. Kindly help me in passing the stored array values present in the jquery function of my jsp page to the servlet.

This is my jquery function present in the jsp page

```
 <script>
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            var checkedRows = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                checkedRows.push(
                  $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                      return $(this).html();
                  }).get()
                ); 
             });        
            console.log( checkedRows );

        });
    </script>
```

**JSP page**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
        <%@page import="web.Products"%>
        <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
        <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            var checkedRows = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                checkedRows.push(
                  $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                      return $(this).html();
                  }).get()
                ); 
             });        
            console.log( checkedRows );

        });
    </script>

    </head>
         <form name="sform" method="post" action="Save_Products"> 
          <table style="width:40%">
              <tr> <th> Brand Name</th>
                  <th> Product Name</th>
                  <th> Description</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td><%
      List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("productlist");
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
      out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"brand_name\" value=\""  + prod.getBrandname() + "\">");
          out.println("<br/>"+prod.getBrandname());

            } %> </td>
           <td><%
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
           out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" checked=\"checked\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
            } } %> </td>
           <td><%
           if(pdts!=null){
           for(Products prod: pdts){
            out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\" value=\""+prod.getDesc()+"\"/><br/>");
        } 
       }  
       } %> </td>  
       </tr>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center">  <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 

          </table>
             </form>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code for passing js array to servlet :

in your jsp add :

```
$.post('Save_Products', {arrayData:checkedRows, mode:"insert"});
```

In your servlet :

```
String[] arrayData=request.getParameterValues("arrayData[]");
```

Comment: Null value is getting printed if I print the arrayData

Comment: Just idea (To avoid uncertainty) : try to put your code into <body></body>
and put js code before </body>

Comment: Not working :(  Is there anything wrong in my jquery function?

Comment: did you check your array before sending to servlet ?

Comment: Values are not getting printed in my browser console. This error is coming "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function"  .Please help me.

Comment: take a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170828/jquery-get-values-of-checked-checkboxes-into-array