# how to bring value from checkbox to controller laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing a display page which display data from a table and there are 3 checkbox which user can check to represents as their choice.

```
<tbody>@foreach($data as $d)
<?php $choice = 0 ?>
<tr>
   <td>{{$d->domain_label}}{{$d->domain_extension}}</td>
   <td>{{$d->domain_reg_date}}</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="R"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="D"></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="H"></td>
   <td><a href="{{ URL::to('/postvalid2/'.$d->domain_label.'/'.$d->domain_extension)}}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" type="submit">Select</button></a></td>
    </tr>@endforeach
```

i've tried using form to display the value for checkbox and it's working. the problem with button is i cannot bring the correct value of domain_label and domain_extension through action.

Comment: If you try with form, then why you need to use button?

Comment: i deleted what i did with the form. coding above is the product when i decide not to use form.

Comment: You can then use jquery to bring value from checkboxes to controller

Comment: can you show me the example on how to call the variable from jquery in controller ?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: <br />
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170828/jquery-get-values-of-checked-checkboxes-into-array

Answer (score 1):

You may use inputs with type `hidden` to send hidden data to controller

```
<input type="hidden" name="domain_label[<?=$d->id?>]" value="<?=$d->domain_label?>">
<input type="hidden" name="domain_extension[<?=$d->id?>]" value="<?=$d->domain_extension?>">
```

Comment: i did. But it will bring the latest data. Like what i did above, i did a foreach which means there will be many data. So the form will detect the latest value of both domain_label and domain_extension. Thats why i decided not to use form

Comment: set name to `domain_label[<?=$d->id?>]` and you will get the array with all data. see updated answer.

Comment: if i did an increment of i and assigned it as the id, would it work the same ? Because the table didnt have any unique id.

Comment: You may use increment. Or open new form in each table's row, so submit button will only submit it's form.

Comment: can we do tht ? I alrdy searched for and it says you cannot put for inside a table's part.

Comment: `<tr><td><form action=''><input><submit></form></td></tr><tr><td><form action=''><input><submit></form></td></tr>`

Comment: hi, i already tried using id. but it still bring the latest data. still won't pick the same data in the same row of the button.