# Add Commas to checkbox array text Output

Tags: jquery, arrays, text, checkbox

I need *","* between values (Commas or new line)
Output now: ab
Expected output: a,b

I'm just not sure where place it exactly. I get an extra comma every time at the start or at the end, like ",a,c" OR "a,c,".

```js
$('.check').click(function() {
  $("#text").val('');
  $(".check").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $("#text").val($("#text").val() + $(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" class="check" id="a" value="a"><label for="a"> a</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" class="check" id="b" value="b"><label for="b"> b</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="c" class="check" id="c" value="c"><label for="c"> c</label><br>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
```

Comment: One way is to concatenate a comma along with each new value. Another way is to build an array of values and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them with a comma. What have you tried and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Thx for Input. just edited the Question to get it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend selecting all checkboxes, [filtering](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to only checked boxes, [mapping](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) values to an array, and [joining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array by a comma.

```js
let $checks = $('.check');

$checks.on('click', function() {

  let values = $checks
    .filter(':checked')
    .map((k, box) => box.value)
    .toArray()
    .join(',');

  $("#text").val(values);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" class="check" id="a" value="a"><label for="a"> a</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" class="check" id="b" value="b"><label for="b"> b</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="c" class="check" id="c" value="c"><label for="c"> c</label><br>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
```

Also see [jQuery get values of checked checkboxes into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170828/jquery-get-values-of-checked-checkboxes-into-array).